# Alternating string of char and int

Tags: java, string

when given a input string i am suppose to break it up into two groups

1. char
2. int.

with these two groups i want to create a new alternating string.

for example

```
abc1234defgh567jk89
```

will transform into

```
a1b2c3d5e6f7j8k9
```

notice that the digit 4,g,h has been discarded.

i figured that a queue can be implemented in this case.

queue1> abc
queue2> 123
index 0 to 2 is a char
index three is a int, so for queue 2 we only take in 3 values.

my question is there a more efficient data structure to perform this operation? 
and during implementation, how to i compare to see if a particular value is a int or a char?

please advise.

Comment: do you need to split it into two groups before alternating characters and numbers? I was thinking you might be able to use regex to get a set of letters and numbers, then split letters and numbers, then alternate letters and numbers?

Comment: In terms of time complexity the best you'll get is O(n) because you have to search the entire String. In terms of space complexity, you're also stuck at O(n) because you need to build a new String.

Answer (score 1):

Treating the string as an array of char integers would make this easier to compare, as you can do a simple comparision on the entry. If array[x]>64 it is a character else it is a number. You can use two pointers to do the interleaving. One for character and the other for integer. Find a character and then advance the integer pointer until it finds a match, then advance them as long as they are both true, then fast forward both of them. For example:

```
char array[]=(char *)string;

int letter=array[0];
int number=array[0];


// Initialize
while(number >= 64)
    number++;
while (letter<64)
    letter++;

//Now that the pointers are initialized, interleave them.

while(letter>=64 && number<64)
{
       output[i++]=letter;
       output[i++]=number;
    number++;
    letter++;
}

// Now you need to advance to the next batch, so you need to see the comparison false and then true again.
```

....

Answer (score 1):

You are right, a queue is a good data structure for this problem. If, however, you want fancier methods at hand, a `Linked List` would be another very similar alternative.

To check if a particular value is a letter or a number, you can use the Character class. For example,

```
String sample = "hello1";

Character.isLetter( sample.charAt(0) ); // returns true
Character.isLetter( sample.charAt(5) ); // returns false
```

Answer (score 1):

> how to i compare to see if a particular value is a int or a char?

You can do something like this:

```
String string = "abc1234defgh567jk89";
for(int i=0; i<string.length;i++){
    int c = (int)string.charAt(i);
    boolean isChar = 97<=c&&c<=122 || 65<=c&&c<=90;
    boolean isNum = 48<=c&&c<=57;
    if(!isChar && !isNum){
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("I don't know what you are")
    }
}
```

About the datastructutures, personally I will use two single linked list, one for chars and one for numbers and every character will be stored in a different node. *Why?*, well if you store the characters (in general, I mean chars and ints) in groups of threes later you will have to add more code to split those groups and put chars and ints together, putting them in a linked list makes sense because

1. you can put as much nodes as you want (or memory lets you but let's assume is infinite)
2. data will be stored in order (which looks like some kind of requirement you have in order to display the output, also this discards trees and stacks(FILO))
3. since you only need to go forward when generating the output a double linked list will be over engineering.

To generate the output:
Having two datastructures let's you add another check like:

```
if(listChars.size() != listNums.size()){
    throw new IllegalArgumentException("Wrong input!!!")
}
```

Additionally,
Reviewing the list will take you `O(n)` time, memory used will be `O(n)`, reviewing both list will take you  `O(n/m)` where m is the size of the initial group of chars.
You can do that like this:

```
Iterator<Character> iterChar = listChar.iterator();
Iterator<Integer> iterNum = listChar.iterator();
String result = "";
while(iterChar.hasNext() && iterNum.hasNext() ){
    result+=iterChar.next()+iterNum.next();
}
```

Finally, you can use queues or linked list here both give you the same in this scenario

Answer (score 1):

To check if the next char is a letter or number you can use this:

```
public static boolean isNumber(char c) { return c >= '0' && c <= '9'; }
public static boolean isLetter(char c) { return c >= 'a' && c <= 'z'; }
```

These functions find the index of the next number or letter, starting at pos `i`:

```
public static int nextNumber(String s, int i) {
    while(i < s.length() && !isNumber(s.charAt(i))) i++;
    return i;
}

public static int nextLetter(String s, int i) { 
    while(i < s.length() && !isLetter(s.charAt(i))) i++;
    return i;
}
```

You don't really need a data structure, all you need is 3 pointers:

```
public static String alternate(String s){
    // pointers
    int start = 0, mid = 0, end = 0;

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(s.length());
    while(end < s.length()){
        // E.g. for 'abc1234' {start, mid, end} = {0, 3, 7}
        start = Math.min(nextLetter(s, end), nextNumber(s, end));
        mid =   Math.max(nextLetter(s, end), nextNumber(s, end));
        end =   Math.max(nextLetter(s, mid), nextNumber(s, mid));

        for(int i = 0; i < Math.min(mid - start, end - mid); i++)
            sb.append(s.charAt(start + i)).append(s.charAt(mid + i));
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```

Running the example below outputs the desired result: `a1b2c3d5e6f7j8k9`

```
public static void main(String... args){
    System.out.println(alternate("abc1234defgh567jk89"));
}
```